# Oracle not dropping datafiles after dropping tablespace

Tags: oracle10g

So I created a `tablespace` and added two `datafiles` to it but when i dropped the table space using `drop tablespace tbs1 including contents` it didn't drop the `datafiles` and i was wondering why or if i did anything wrong. 
If you do know a better way to do it feel free to provide it.

Also why does a user default `tablespace` stay after deleting that specific tablespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It didn't remove the datafiles because you didn't ask it to, try

```
DROP TABLESPACE tbs1 INCLUDING CONTENTS AND DATAFILES;
```

The only real answer to your secondary question is `because it does`.  Oracle decided to make it work that way and I think this might be because it's difficult to decide which tablespace is to be used instead. i.e. it is probably safer to leave the user with a default of a non-existent tablespace until you define a new default than it is to randomly pick one; after all dropping a tablespace and its contents is not normally a trivial event but something with ramifications that should be carefully considered in advance.